# Gravity problem solver in Factor

Tags: coordinate-system, physics, factor-lang

After answering a question about Factor, I decided that it looked interesting. To get the hang of the syntax and such, I decided to write some basic physics code to "solve" [the three-body problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem). Then, I realized that math is harder than I thought it would be, so instead I just made a vocabulary to solve some basic problems about classical gravitational attraction.

I'm looking for advice on:

- **Idiomatic-ness**: The functions feel pretty long for Factor, but they seem about as short as they'll get.
- **Naming**: Some of my function names are subpar, but I can't find better names for them.
- **Separation**: I feel like the vector arithmetic should be in its own vocabulary, but I'm not sure. Also, I have no idea how to do that.
- **Removing rounding errors**: The program is fairly accurate, but some rounding error leads to ever-so-slightly wrong numbers (i.e. \$49.99999999999999\$ instead of \$50\$)

```
USING: locals math.functions math.vectors math.trig math.constants ;
IN: q.physics.gravitational-attraction

TUPLE: body
  { mass     initial: 0       }
  { position initial: { 0 0 } }
  { velocity initial: { 0 0 } }
;
:: array>body ( array -- obj )
  body new
    array first         >>mass
    array second 2 head >>position
    array third 2 head  >>velocity
;
: >body ( mass position velocity -- obj )
  3array array>body
;

! Constants
SYMBOLS: G ;
! Throws an error if it's 6.674e−11 so let's use 1
1 G set

:: vector-between ( from to -- v )
  to first from first -
  to second from second -
  2array
;

:: dot ( u v -- rad )
  u first v first * u second v second * +
  u first sq u second sq + sqrt v first sq v second sq + sqrt *
  /
;
: angle-between ( u v -- rad ) dot ;

:: v+ ( u v -- sum )
  u first v first +
  u second v second +
  2array
;

:: s*v ( k v -- scaled )
  v first k *
  v second k *
  2array
;

:: -1*v ( v -- neg )
  v first -1 *
  v second -1 *
  2array  
;

:: magnitude ( v -- num )
  v first sq v second sq + sqrt
;

:: unit ( v -- unit )
  v magnitude :> len
  v first len /
  v second len /
  2array
;

:: force-on ( obj from -- force )
  obj position>> from position>> vector-between :> vec
  G get obj mass>> * from mass>> *
  vec magnitude
  /
  vec unit s*v
;

:: forces ( bodies -- forces )
  bodies [
    :> body
    body bodies remove [
      body swap force-on
    ] map
  ] map
;
```

I don't know the math well enough to test the edge cases, but I did check with this code:

```
SYMBOLS: b1 b2 b3 ;
10 { 0 0 } { 0 0 } >body b1 set
10 { 1 0 } { 0 0 } >body b2 set
10 { 0 1 } { 0 0 } >body b3 set
b1 get b2 get b3 get 3array forces [| f | f first f second v+ ] map .
```

which gave me the result:

```
{
    { 100.0 100.0 }
    { -150.0 49.99999999999999 }
    { 49.99999999999999 -150.0 }
}
```

And according to my math, that's correct. Note that the results are in terms of \$G\$, not multiplying by it, since it gives me an error when I try to put in `6.674e−11`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite skilled enough at Factor yet to review your code in full, but I would just like to note as a response to

> I don't know the math well enough to test the edge cases, but I did check with this code

Factor has *really* slick builtin unit-testing. [Here are the docs](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/word-unit-test,tools.test.html); I'll pull an example from my `factor/work` directory:

```
USING: tools.test mk-initialism ;
IN: mk-initialism.tests

{ "LASER" } [ "Light Ablah by S of Ed Radiof" >initialism ] unit-test
{ "USA"   } [ "United S OF Americaof" >initialism ]         unit-test
{ "USA"   } [ "united states and america" >initialism ]     unit-test
{ "JTW"   } [ "Jordan Of the World" >initialism ]           unit-test
```

To create the test file, open the listener and do:

```
USE: tools.scaffold
"q.physics.gravitational-attraction" scaffold-tests
```

To run the tests, just run `"q.physics.gravitational-attraction" test`.